# Read and Write File Parallely in c#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have following code snippet in c# in which I am reading file parallely and replacing some text after reading and then writing back to different location. 
I am not getting any exception but file is not written to different location

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly object _loc = new object();
    public static string FileRead(string fileName)
    {
        string pattern = @"the";
        var result = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        var replacedText = Regex.Replace(result, pattern, "XXXX");
        var path = Path.Combine(@"D:\Demo2", fileName);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false))
            sw.Write(replacedText);
        return replacedText;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Demo", "*.txt");
        Parallel.ForEach(files, x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FileName={0}\tNOC={1}",x, FileRead(x).Length);
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Flush`ing the `StreamWriter` make any difference?

Comment: Are there no files in Demo2 or are they the same as the old ones?

Comment: @HenkHolterman:No files in Demo2

Comment: @paul The writer is in a `using` block, which will dispose it after the write, and disposing it closes the writer which also flushes the buffer.

Comment: @paul:Flush is also not working

Comment: Btw. if you [ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143369.aspx) you could also [WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143376.aspx). And reading and writing text files without specifying the encoding might lead to unwanted surprises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A repro for your Path.Combine() call is:

```
  var fileName = @"D:\Demo\foo.txt";
  var path = Path.Combine(@"D:\Demo2", fileName);
```

This does **not** do what you think it does.  It will actually overwrite the original file and not write anything to D:\Demo2.  Fix:

```
  var path = Path.Combine(@"D:\Demo2", Path.GetFileName(fileName));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your files collection will contain *full* filenames, your code assumes partial (relative) names.

```
       public static string FileRead(string fileName)
        {
           ...
         //var path = Path.Combine(@"D:\Demo2", fileName);
           var path = Path.GetFilename(fileName);       // check 'path' in debugger
           path = Path.Combine(@"D:\Demo2", path);
           ...
        }
```

======

Some general remarks:

- Parallel I/O does not always work. Your `D:\` better be an SSD but even then.
- You will get a bigger boost from `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`, especially with many files.

Comment: No success still getting empty directory

Comment: Hmm, debug the writing part.

Answer (score -2):

Apart from the other answers: I guess what you want to do is to write asynchronously, not in parallel. When calling this in parallel you have more than one thread using your instance of the `StreamWriter`. The `StreamWriter` is not thread-safe and in your snippet you don't care about threading. You also want to parallelize work that is carried out in a sequential way anyways.

I'd suggest to use the `WriteAsync` methods of the your `StreamWriter` instance.

Comment: No, the StreamWriters are local to their Thread. No problem there.

Comment: I thought since we have a number of threads involved here, all accessing the same object, this might get an issue. But anyways I thinkg the sequential VS parallel thoughts are still valid

Comment: It's not the 'same' object each time. Multiple copies.